# Should I be using this white pipe to drain my sump pump?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, sump-pump, landscaping

When I moved into this house earlier this year, the sump pump had a black hose connected to the pipe like the one here except the old one was super beat up (probably got ran over by a lawnmower).

I bought a new hose and it’s been working fine but I’m wondering if I should be using whatever that white pipe in the ground is?  I tried to find another end to that pipe but couldn’t find it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is presumably a clogged or poorly installed underground drain for the gutter downspout and/or sump.

Presumably it's now disused due to clogging or dumping water back in the basement to be pumped in circles.

Without cleaning out and/or correcting, it's probably still clogged or poorly installed. If cleaned out or corrected (or replaced wholesale with a correct underground drain) it might be preferable to the present arrangement.

If you get real winter, you might need a larger diameter sump pipe so it does not freeze up, rather than the small black corrugated.

Comment: Thanks! We do get real winters here, and it’s already getting cold. Is it sufficient enough to remove the black hose for the winter? Or do I need to get someone to look into the potentially clogged drain?

Comment: You will want the water taken **away** from the building. I was suggesting just changing the small black pipe to something like a 3-4" pipe or section of downspout, sloped to run away from the house so it will drain between pumpouts without collecting a lot of water to freeze into an ice plug. That would be quick and inexpensive, compared to needing a rush job on the underground pipe.

Comment: Gotcha. I found a YouTube video describing exactly what you’re saying. I’ll go hit up the store later today. Thanks again so much!